# Can a curve represented by a polynomial equation having n arbitrary constants, be uniquely determined by n-1 distinct points?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let there be a polynomial $f(X)$, $X \in R^m$  with $n$ unknown arbitrary constants. 
Consider , the equation  $ f(X) = 0$. Now, given $k$ distinct points in $R^m$   which satisfies the aforementioned equation such that $k \leq n$,  does it trivially follow or if not, how should it be proved(or provided with a counter example) that the $k$ linear equations we get form an independent system of equations?

Comment: Are the unknown coefficients the _only_ coefficients of $f$ or are there other nonzero coefficients you do know?

Comment: As far as my problem is concerned, all the coefficients of $f$ are unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is coming from the determinant of the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix).

Comment: Thanks, it does answer my question when the polynomial $f(X)$ is in one variable. But what if, as originally stated, $X \in R^m $?

Comment: Never mind, the equations corresponding to $k$ given points do not necessarily form an independent system when $X \in R^m$

Answer (score 2):

In one dimension, knowing $n$ different zeroes of a degree-$n$ polynomial will allow you to determine its $n+1$ coefficients up to a common constant factor. (Of course not all polynomials *have* $n$ different zeroes, but never mind that).

Things are not so nice in higher dimensions. For example if I tell you that $f(x,y)$ is a second-degree polynomial, and that
$$ f(0,0) = f(0,1) = f(0,2) = f(0,3) = f(0,4) = f(0,5) = 0$$
then you have just as many zeroes as there there are coefficients to find (a quadratic in 2 variables has 6 coefficients), but you still haven't learned anything useful about the relation between the coefficients of $x$, $xy$ and $x^2$.

Comment: Thanks, your example in the second paragraph, clarifies that in higher dimensions, $n-1$ distinct points may not uniquely determine the curve. But, as you stated before, that when $X \in R$ such a thing is indeed true. The proof of the same was what  I was asking and it comes from the determinant of  Vandermonde matrix as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Your six points all lie on the same line. On the other hand, $5$ points in general position, i.e. such that no triplet is collinear, are enough to uniquely identify a conic.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of $d$-variate polynomial of degree $m$ is $Q=\dim \pi_m(\mathbb{R}^d)={m+d\choose d}$.

One would hope that $Q$ points -- roots would be enough to uniquely determine the polynomial. Indeed for $m<2$ this is the case. But for $m\geq2$ the layout of points matter, some layouts (e.g. "collinear") do not work, are not enough, the points must be more spread out, *unisolvent* (*). (It's a consequence of Mairhuber–Curtis theorem proving that there are no Haar spaces in $m\geq2$).

(*) Points are called $\pi_m(\mathbb{R}^d)$-unisolvent if the zero polynomial is the only polynomial from $\pi_m(\mathbb{R}^d)$ that vanishes on all of them.